# How to make a custom event system framerate friendly?

Tags: unity, events, frame-rate

I have a simple event system:

```
class GameEvent{
    float executionTime;
    Action action;
}

class EventMgr : MonoBehaviour{

    List<GameEvent> events = new List<GameEvent>();

    void Update(){

        float timeNow = Time.time;

        for(int i=events.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(timeNow >= events[i].executionTime)
            {
                exents[i].action();
                events.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }


    public void ScheduleEvent(float delay, Action action){
        events.Add(new GameEvent(){
            action = action,
            executionTime = Time.time + delay;
        });
    }
}
```

Then,

I schedule events like this:

```
eventMgr.ScheduleEvent(0.1f, () => {
    // EVENT A - should be fired first
};

eventMgr.ScheduleEvent(0.15f, () => {
    // EVENT B - should be fired second
};
```

Everything works fine when I play on `60 FPS`. `Update()` is fired once every `~0.016s`. When I play the game on a device with `20-40FPS` - things got a little bit tricky. Events seem to run in an incorrect order (Event B fired before event A).

The only possible cause is of course the framerate itself.
If the game runs at `20FPS`, `Update()` would be called less frequently and both of these events would be fired in the same frame - and then, the order of their execution depends on the list itself.

What to do here?
Is there any trick to prevent this, is there any pattern for accurate, ordered event system in games which is FPS friendly?

Comment: Granted I haven't had my coffee yet, but isn't your condition (`events[i].executionTime >= timeNow`) reversed? Don't you want to execute the events for which the `executionTime` has already *passed*?

Comment: If `timeNow` is at `0` and `executionTime` is at `1` it means that we've just scheduled an event for `1 second`. Then, `timeNow` grows, grows, grows and after one second it has a value like `1.0013424` - which makes the `condition == true`, fires the event and removes it from the list.

Comment: I understand that, but am I missing something? Your code executes events when `executionTime` is **greater** than `timeNow`, what you just described is the opposite. if `timeNow` is at `0` and `executionTime` is at `1`, then `executionTime >= timeNow` is `true`, not `false`. The event will be fired immediately.

Comment: Awww nice catch! I've corrected the code. Written from memory :) Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like you could solve it with a priority queue or [min-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). The code to process the queue would look something like this:

```
while(eventQueue.Count > 0 && eventQueue.Peek().executionTime <= Time.time) {
    eventQueue.Dequeue().action();
}
```

This means you have only one check to do on frames when no events happen - you don't have to scan the whole list.

The nature of the priority data structure ensures that the next event to fire is always the first one you check, and when multiple events fire in the same frame, you process them in non-decreasing order of `executionTime`.

Insertion and removal from such a data structure are typically logarithmic, so they remain reasonable even for large collections of events.

Comment: Are these any ready-to-go data structures like a priority queue available in Unity, .NET 4.5?

Comment: It's absent from the standards .NET collections, but easy to whip up your own custom-suited to your needs. It's also a popular enough data structure that you can find implementations in several third-party libraries you could include too, if you want something battle-tested without writing it from scratch yourself.

Comment: @Spectre The quick&dirty solution to see if it works would be to just use a vanilla `List<GameEvent>` and sort it before the code above. If the sorting starts to take too much CPU time (I don' think it will unless the queue contains over a few hundred items), you can start to look for a more efficient self-sorting data structure.

Answer (score 2):

If sufficient time passes between `Update` calls to trigger multiple events, then as you note the actual firing order depends on the order in which you process the list. Since you process the list backwards you will evaluate and thus potentially fire "later" events sooner.

If you want your events to create an implicit dependency through their firing time (e.g., an event `A` with an absolute time `Ta` must fire before any events with absolute time `Tn` > `Ta`), then you need to ensure you process them in that order.

In your case, you could just sort the list by absolute time, either before you process it in `Update` or by ensuring during scheduling you put new events in the proper sorted position.

Sorting the list *backwards* by absolute time means you can continue to process it backwards and rely on the efficiency of removing items from the end of the list (versus from the beginning, which would require moving the remaining items down).

Comment: I suspect if you are removing items from the end, you are probably adding items to the beginning, which has a similar expense.  If this is the case, fancier data structures like a linked list or a circular queue could provide improved performance at the cost of increased code complexity.

Comment: Yes; really a wholly different structure like DMGregory proposes is probably best. I was trying to take a minimally disruptive angle on my answer.